# Installed Centos 7 after Windows and can't boot into CentOS

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I wanted to setup a dual boot for Windows 7 and CentOS 7

I had a Windows 7 machine with 500GB disk.  I shrank the Windows partition to provide space for CentOS 7 (roughly 230GB).  I created a USB CentOS 7 netinstall stick and booted from that. I ran the install configured as best I knew to install CentOS 7 into the free space (rather than over the whole disk).  I did the net install and all seemed to go well but when it rebooted I was back into Windows and can't get into CentOS.

I've rebooted from the USB and tried to fix the situation (carefully) using `cfdisk`, e.g. selecting what I believe is the CentOS boot partition but it reports "missing operating system."  Also `cfdisk` says it can't reread the partition table when I write it with CentOS boot but starting `cfdisk` again seems to show the flag has been set.

Currently the USB CentOS 7 netinstall shows me the following partitions on the disk:

```
## DATA  
/home 168GB centos-home  

## SYSTEM  
/boot 500MB sda3  
/ 51GB centos-root  
swap 3.85GB centos-swap
```

The "other" Windows partitions are:

```
ntfs 100MB sda1  
ntfs 253GB sda2
```

This looks ok BUT when I go into CentOS 7 Installation again it is telling me I have to create mount points for the root partition.  I didn't do this originally as I thought it would be done automatically when I clicked "Click here to create them automatically" for the disk setup the first time I installed.

And the partition table accessed using `cfdisk` from "Rescue a CentOS system..." looks like this:

```
Unusable 1MB  
sda1 Primary ntfs 105MB    
sda2 Primary ntfs 265GB  
sda3 Boot Primary xfs 525MB    
sda5 NC Logical LVM2_member 235GB  
Logical Free space 0.03MB
```

As mentioned, when I try to boot with this configuration I get "missing operating system." If I change the boot flag back to sda1 then it boots into Windows 7 fine.

#### UPDATE #1

I (re)installed `grub2` using `grub2-install` from netinstall on `/dev/sda` and now when I boot from the disk I get the `grub` prompt. I can using it to chain load into Windows. However, when I try to boot into CentOS 7 I get some sort of trace/dump.

I used:

```
linux  (hd0,msdos3)/vmlinuz-3... root=/dev/sda3
initrd (hd0,msdos3/initrd-plymouth...
boot
```

**NOTE:** I believe `linux` is the primary boot partition for CentOS

Trying the above just crashes.

#### UPDATE #2

I installed NTFS-3G and NTFSPROGS using `yum` from the EPEL repository.

I ran `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and then rebooted to find Windows 7 (Loader) in the boot menu. But when I choose it I get:

```
error: no such device 978778...
error: hd1 cannot get C/H/S values....
```

which doesn't sound very good at all, but at least some progress.

I should also say that I now have CentOS 7 only on the internal drive and I'm working on this drive as an external USB drive (hence `/dev/sdb`).

Can someone please help me to get Windows to boot?

I have a Unix background but mostly use Mac OS X.  I always come unstuck on setting up Windows and Linux dual boot.

Finally, I have CentOS 6.5 system running fine on another machine, as well as my Mac.

Answer (score 4):

You probably mounted the wrong Windows partition.

Look for a small partition of 100 or 300MB (the *Boot Partition* of Windows), mount it and then run the command again.

If you are still having problems, add following to the end of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Windows"{
    set root='(hd0,0)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

This is assuming the Windows boot partition is the first partition of the first hard disk.

Don't forget to run `grub2-mkconfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Mount the windows Partition. (If you can't mount install **ntfsprogs-2013.1.13-5.el7.x86_64.rpm** and **ntfs-3g-2013.1.13-5.el7.x86_64.rpm**)

Run as root `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  After many attempts to get this working I put in a new disk and installed just Centos 7.  However, I still want to get the other disk with Windows working so I will put the disk in another machine and follow your direction.  Thanks again!

Comment: Did that.  Now getting entry in boot menu :-)

But now get:
error: no such device 787776677...
error: hd1 cannot get C/H/S values...

Comment: this worked great with windows 7 and CentOS 7. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the CentOS bootloader (whether it is LILO or GRUB). The bootloader installer should recognize OSes in your machine and automatically show you OS choices in booting time. CMIIW.

Comment: Thanks Ade.  I believe CentOS 7 uses Grub2, so I will reinstall that.  I guess it goes in the 500MB boot partition but I thought the problem would relate more to the MBR (or something like that).  Will the Grub2 set that up appropriately?

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying a dual boot with window 7 and centos 7 for 2 days and I did 
it. Just follow simple steps

Install window 7

Then centos 7

When you restart the pc you will not see any boot option for windows 7 in grub.

Boot into centos switch to `su`

use command `cfdisk`

Then check for flags where boot is written notify that partition

Then open grub file in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg 
first backup the grub.cfg file by copying it as grub.old.cfg 
open the file and edit it with

```
menuentry "WINDOWS"{
set root='(hd0,msdos1)' 
chainloader +1
}
```

change the value of msdos with the partition where the boot flag is given.
as if boot flag is in /dev/sda1 then msdos1 if /dev/sda2 then msdos2.

Don't forget to run `grub2-mkconfig`

I hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Hope the OP selects this as the accepted answer. Worked perfectly for me: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2015/12/fixing-grub-boot-options-if-your-linux.html, but it would have been better to have a third-party boot-loader which automatically recognizes OS'es on partitions: http://superuser.com/questions/1009739/have-separate-bootloaders-for-windows-and-linux-on-a-single-hard-disk

Answer (score 1):

Found that adding File 11_windows in `/etc/grub.d` was more helpful:

Contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat << EOF
menuentry "WINDOWS"{
set root='(hd0,msdos1)' 
chainloader +1
}
EOF
```

Then ran `grub2-mkconfig` after saving backup of `grub.cfg` in `/boot/grub2`.

Results included added Entry "WINDOWS" in grub menu during start up.

My case was for Windows10, but should be the same.

Comment: Format of grub2-mkconfig command:

Comment: cd /boot/grub2;  grub2-mkconfig --output=grub.cfg

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying a dual boot with window 7 and centos 7 for two days and I did it. Just follow simple steps 
Install window 7 
Then centos 7 
When you restart the pc you will not see any boot option for windows 7 in grub. 
Boot into centos switch to su 
use command cfdisk 
Then check for flags where boot is written notify that partition 
Then open grub file in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg first backup the grub.cfg file by copying it as grub.old.cfg open the file and edit it with

menuentry "WINDOWS"{
set root='(hd0,msdos1)' 
chainloader +1
}
change the value of msdos with the partition where the boot flag is given. as if boot flag is in /dev/sda1 then msdos1 if /dev/sda2 then msdos2.

Don't forget to run grub2-mkconfig