# saving file to usb stick while using linux boot stick

Tags: centos, boot, dual-boot, boot-loader, live-usb

I am using [the instructions in this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-u_va6ZxOk) to install CentOS 7 on a new computer that is running Windows 8.  The tutorial uses [UniversalUSBInstaller from PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/), but the installation is failing.  Instead of the expected gnome gui, I get a `#` prompt and an error message that includes the following:

```
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a  
USB stick or /boot after mounting them and attaching it to a  
bug report.
```

**Can someone give clear instructions for simply saving `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt` so that I can subsequently view it from inside windows?**

I know the letter that windows uses to label the usb drive, but I do not know how to manipulate it from the `#` prompt that my pc gives when it fails to launch CentOS from that usb drive.

If I could get a detailed error log from the attempt to start CentOS from the boot stick, then I could proceed with trying to fix the problem and successfully install CentOS 7 to make this a dual boot machine.

NOTE: The pc on which I am trying to use the boot stick requires me to press `esc` when I turn on the PC power instead of F12 or F2 to get boot options.

---

**EDIT:**

---

per @terndon's advice, I typed `ls /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt`, which resulted in the terminal printing `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt`.  Also, I found that it is the [Dracut Emergency Shell](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dracut.8.html).  But I have never used this before, any I only know how to access the USB drive from within windows.  **How can I use the `Dracut emergency shell` to save the document to the usb drive I a location which I can then find and open from within windows?**

Also, I opened up `Disk Management` within windows, and the windows partition on the D: drive is named `Windows`.  So I interpret @terdon's advice to be:

```
mkdir /foo;  
mount /dev/Windows /foo;  
cp /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt dev/Windows/foo/rdsosreport.txt;
```

And then log into windows and look for C:/foo/rdsosreport.txt?

Is this what I should try?  Or should I try a different syntax?  The process of getting out of windows and generating that prompt is cumbersome, so I am asking here rather than getting stuck there and having to close up again and get back here before doing more research.

---

**SECOND EDIT:**

---

As per @terdon's suggestion, I typed `df -h`, but the terminal replied with `sh: df: command not found`.  I then pressed `esc`, and the terminal replied asking if I wanted a list of all 225 possibilities.  I typed `y`, and the terminal replied by printing out 225 command options, too many for me to hand write and retype type.

Comment: Why is windows relevant here? The `#` is most likely a Linux root shell. Try running `ls /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt`, what are the results?

Comment: @terdon I will run that now.  Thank you.  The issue is that I do not know how to record output other than to hand write what is on the screen and then to type it again here when I get back into windows. I will report back shortly.

Comment: If that works, we know we're at a UNIX shell. This means you should be able to mount your Windows hard drive (something like `mkdir /foo; mount /dev/sdXN /foo` where `sdXN` is the partition of your Windows system, for example `sdb2`.

Comment: @terdon Please see edit to my OP.  Thank you.

Comment: OK, so we know you're in a UNIX shell. Now, please [edit] your question and post the output of `df -h` from that shell. That should give us the name of your Windows drive. There's no reason to use this emergency shell you found, all the necessary tools should already be there. The partition will not be called `Windows` it will be something like `sdb2`.

Comment: @terdon Please see **SECOND EDIT** at the end of my OP.  `df` does not seem to be among the 225 legal commands.

Comment: @terdon I am not sure how to proceed with this.  Are you willing to continue coaching me?

Comment: Not tonight I'm afraid, no. It's 1 am here. However, I think you're treating the symptom and  not the cause. You shouldn't have to do all this. Try creating a bootable CentOS USB USB using a different tool. Not all of them play nice with all distros. Have a look at `unetbootin` or `yumi` or any of the various ones listed on the pendrivelinux page. Try with a few different tools, one of them should let you install normally.

Comment: @terdon I transcribed a list of valid commands accepted by the Dracut emergency shell to make this easier for people to try to help.  Are you willing to take a look?  The list is at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210439/unknown-maxwell-chipset-on-centos-7-install