# Booting back to Windows

Tags: linux

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I think I made a mistake when installing because I wanted this to be dual boot but now the computer automatically goes to Ubuntu every time I switch it on.

It doesn't even give me the options, it just goes straight to Linux. The OS is still new so I have no third party softwares installed.

I would like to know I can go back to get the dual boot option or at least go back to Windows.

Comment: Try pressing ESC when the plain purple screen shows up to halt grub and show its boot menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate (possible!) : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169787/windows-boot-option-is-missing-after-installing-centos-7-how-can-i-get-it-back

Answer (score 0):

During installation, did you by accident wipe your HDD clean ?

If not, try booting into ubuntu and check in the file manager whether there are other drives you can access. If you do find the windows partitions try clicking on it and getting access. If this is the case try installing a package called boot-repair. And then running it from ubuntu.  Paste the following into a terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The program GUI is not that confusing.

If this is pertaining to a UEFI / Secure boot issue, consult this link:

[UEFI | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)