# How to get Windows on grub menu? Using two HDDs; Windows bootloader on first

Tags: centos, windows, grub2, uefi, grub-legacy

Here is some background. I had a 1TB HDD with Windows inside it. Partitions something like this:

[image: partition of first hard drive]

I bought an another hard drive of 2TB and wanted to dedicate 1TB to Windows and another to Linux. Here is a screenshot of the second hard drive.

[image: partition table of second hard drive]

As you can see, `sda2` had Windows bootloader at time of installing CentOS 7. I intentionally tried to install CentOS bootloader (i.e. grub?) in first hard drive so that CentOS can detect it. But seems like CentOS couldn't detect Windows even after that.

Here's my output from `fdisk -l` if screenshot is not enough:

```
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1           34       262177    128M  Microsoft reser Microsoft reserved partition
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
 2       264192   1953646591  931.5G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
 3   1953646592   1955743743      1G  Microsoft basic 
 4   1955743744   3907028991  930.5G  Linux LVM       
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       616447    300M  Windows recover Basic data partition
 2       616448       819199     99M  EFI System      EFI system partition
 3       819200      1081343    128M  Microsoft reser Microsoft reserved partition
 4      1081344   1048575999  499.5G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
 5   1048576000   1887436799    400G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
 6   1887436800   1953521663   31.5G  Microsoft basic Basic data partition
 7   1953521664   1953523711      1M  BIOS boot parti 

Disk /dev/mapper/cl-01: 981.9 GB, 981873983488 bytes, 1917722624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-00: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-13bc4611-477c-4df5-bfb7-b2bbd696e18b: 981.9 GB, 981871886336 bytes, 1917718528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

---

I [researched a bit](https://askubuntu.com/a/98231/49715) and found that I can do `update-grub` command. But that here is not possible. CentOS 7 uses different grub than Ubuntu's grub (correct me if I am wrong).

I also found a `grub2-mkconfig` [method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169793/22240), but this command doesn't finds Windows bootloader:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-fd2ff737d87642cc87d59785cf5f2390
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-fd2ff737d87642cc87d59785cf5f2390.img
done
```

This is a UEFI capable computer.

---

I made a discovery, found this:

[image]

Is this of any use?

Comment: Please explain the downvotes. This question is a result of good research. Request any data if needed.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am exactly same problem in 2020. Windows is gone.

Comment: Not actually @Rishabh, I'm a full time Linux user. I've given all the space to my Linux.